# jQuery find data attributes with one datakey and multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrive all the objects with one datakey and multiple values, for QuickSand:

```
<ul>
  <li data-company="Microsoft">Steve</li>
  <li data-company="Google">Jobs</li>
  <li data-company ="Facebook">Michael</li>
  <li data-company ="Google">Richard</li>
  <li data-company ="Facebook">Tim</li>
</ul>
```

How can i retreve all the li items with data-company Microsoft and Google (these two values are in a array) like this:

```
var itemes = $('ul').find('li[data-comapany={"Microsoft","Google"}]');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an array of the required companies, and check for each li if the data is contained in that array:

```js
var companies = ["Microsoft", "Google"];

$(function() {

  var items = $('ul li').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).data("company"), companies) > -1;
  });

  items.css({
    "position": "relative",
    "margin-left": "25px"
  });
  console.log(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-company="Microsoft">Steve</li>
  <li data-company="Google">Jobs</li>
  <li data-company="Facebook">Michael</li>
  <li data-company="Google">Richard</li>
  <li data-company="Facebook">Tim</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter it:

```
var itemes = $('ul').find('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('company').match(/Microsoft|Google/);
});
```

### -DEMO-

To handle case for `LI` without any `data-company` set, you should use:

```
var itemes = $('ul').find('li').filter(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('company');
    return data ? data.match(/Microsoft|Google/) : null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var companies = ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Waffle House'];

companies.forEach(function(company, index) {
    companies[index] = "li[data-company='" + company + "']";
});

$('ul').find(companies.join(',')).css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine selectors:

```
var items = $("[data-company*='Microsoft'], [data-company*='Google']");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)